# calabash-android undefined method for second step

Tags: android, cucumber, calabash

I'm new to calabash, and I am trying to run a test, and calabash recognizes my first step and it passes, but for the second one i get an undefined method error,

my feature file is:

```
Feature: Sign-in page
Scenario: Go to dashboard with skip login
Given I am on the Login Screen
When I touch the “Skip Login” button
Then I should see the Main Screen
```

and my rb file is

```
Given(/^I am on the Login Screen$/) do
  element_exists("button marked:'authenticate'")
  end

When(/^I touch the "Skip Login" button$/) do
  tap_mark 'skip_login'
end

Then(/^I should see the Main Screen$/) do
  wait_for_elements_exist("label text: 'HeaderText'")
end
```

When it reaches the "When" step, the app closes on my phone.
Can someone please help me with this?

The output is:

```
Given I am on the Login Screen          # features/step_definitions/calabash
```

_steps.rb:1
    When I touch the "Skip Login" button    # features\my_first.feature:4
    Then I should see the Main Screen       # features/step_definitions/calabash
_steps.rb:9

1 scenario (1 undefined)
3 steps (1 skipped, 1 undefined, 1 passed)
0m22.691s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

When(/^I touch the "Skip Login" button$/) do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

One more detail, if I take the second step and move it instead of the first, it will press the button.I can't understand why this is happening, and why it will not do the second step

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a "smart quotes" problem to me:

`When I touch the “Skip Login” button`

Those are not regular double quotes `"`.

Since you are not using a regex in the step definition, I recommend this:

```
Given I am on the Login Screen
When I touch the Skip Login button
Then I should see the Main Screen

When(/^I touch the Skip Login button$/) do
  tap_mark 'skip_login'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, see the logcat for details why you app crashes.

I think you are running an very old version of Calabash-Android. In the newer releases, and invalid query should never crash the app. `wait_for_elements_exist("label text: 'HeaderText'")` will crash the app in old versions of Calabash-Android, as you have a space after `text:` which is invalid.

A newer version of Calabash-Android would raise a Ruby error telling you about the misformed query.

Comment: I checked my version, it is 0.5.10, and I also deleted the space, but it is still the same as before.Also I removed that step, and it still does the same. If I run the command from the console it works

Answer (score 0):

The output from your tests would be good to have. But other than that in you step you have put

```
tap_mark 'skip_login'
```

So it will attempt to find a text with that exact text. But based on your feature file I am guessing that what you actually have on the button is

> Skip Login

And so the tap_mark command fails.

And this is just a guess but is "skip_login" the id of the button? If you want to use that to decide what to click do something like

```
touch "button id:'skip_login'"
```

Comment: It sounds strange. One thing that might be an issue. Is that the step you have defined is a copy of the predefined step, so I don't think you actually need to define it yourself. See list of predefined steps here https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/canned_steps.md